# How to add additional logo in drupal 6

Tags: 6

While configuring my theme, I am able to configure my Logo on *Logo image settings*, but I need to configure one more logo, which will be shown in a different region.

Is there any module available or guide on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you please expand details?

Comment: I created the theme. I need to place main logo in header-top region. so i used $logo in my page.tpl.php. So if i want to change the logo, i will loggin with admin credentials and while configuring the theme i will change the logo. I need the same way to configure one more different logo in header region. and it should be configurable from theme configuration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *certain* this question has been answered before, but I can't seem to find it, so here goes.

If you need more than one logo, just avoid using the normal theme settings, as they are easy to get started with, but rather limited in flexibility.

Instead create a separate storage for the logos, say a 'Logo' content type, and upload each logo as an image. This will easily give you the flexibility you need.